# Convergence of Newton Iteration Sequence

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

Given a function $f: x\mapsto e^x - x- 2$, we try to find solutions to the equation $f(x) = 0$ with Newton's method. It is known that this equation has 2 solutions $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$, with $\xi_1 > 0$ and $\xi_2 < 0$. Now, given any $x_0\in [\xi_1, +\infty)$ or $x_0\in(-\infty, \xi_2]$, I can prove that the Newton iteration sequence $(x_k)$ defined by

$$
x_{k+1} = x_k - \frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}\quad \forall k\in\mathbb{N}
$$

will converge to $\xi_1$ (when $x_0 \geqslant \xi_1$) or $\xi_2$ (when $x_0 \leqslant \xi_2$), respectively. Now, what if I choose the starting point $x_0$ on $(\xi_2, 0)\cup(0, \xi_1)$? How could I prove that that the Newton iteration sequences starting from these points will converge/diverge? Any help will be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

The function is strictly convex, the tangent thus always below the function. The function value at a tangent root is consequently positive. This then implies that if $f(x_0)>0$ that then the sequence of Newton iterates has $f(x_k)>0$ and it converges monotonously towards the closest root.

If now $f(x_0)<0$ and $f'(x_0)\ne 0$, that is, in the case in question with $x_0\ne 0$, the tangent root will again lead to $f(x_1)>0$ and from then on the iteration follows the above case. Now confirm that $x_1$ has the same sign as $x_0$ to determine to which root the sequence converges.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! I should have been aware that it does not matter whether $x_1$ will be greater than $\xi_1$ (or smaller than $\xi_2$) when $f(x_0) < 0$. I was just struggling with proving the monotonicity of $(x_k)$, which now makes no difference.

Comment: Yes, if $f(x_k)>0$, then the tangent has a negative value at the function root, so the tangent root $x_{k+1}$ is strictly between $x_k$ and the next function root, thus the monotonicity of the sequence.